# Azure: Is the HttpContext.Current.Session object shared by all WebRole instances?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, azure

I'm testing a **WebRole** with **multiples instances** in Windows Azure to test the load balancer. The code that I have to authenticate users is the following:

```
    protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpCookie authCookie = 
            HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies
               [FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];

        if (authCookie != null)
        {
            FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = 
                FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);

            SetUserCredentials(authTicket.Name, authTicket.UserData);
        }
    }

    private void SetUserCredentials(string userName, string securityConfig)
    {
        Credentials auth = GetSessionCredentials();

        if (auth == null && HttpContext.Current.Session != null)
        {
            log.DebugFormat("Credentials not available in session variable. Building credentials to __SessionSID.");

            SID sid = 
               AuthenticationHelper.Get().
                  GetAuthenticatedSIDFromName(userName, securityConfig);

            if (sid == null)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
                return;
            }

            auth = new Credentials(sid);

            if (HttpContext.Current.Session != null)
            {
                log.DebugFormat("Saving credentials in a session variable");
                HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("__SessionSID", auth);
            }
        }

        log.DebugFormat("Time setting user credentials for user: {0} {1}ms", userName, Environment.TickCount - ini);
    }

    private Credentials GetSessionCredentials()
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current == null)
            return null;
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session == null)
            return null;

        return HttpContext.Current.Session["__SessionSID"] as Credentials;
    }
```

Here are my questions. I tested the WebRole with two instances in Azure:

- Suppose I login and the WebRole instance A, performs the authentication.
- When I make a new requests, and the request goes to the WebRole instance B, the authTicket in the `Current.Request.Cookies` and the  `HttpContext.Current.Session["__SessionSID"]` were ok.

Someone could explain it? I the session shared among all the WebRole instances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all falls down to the `Session State Provider` configuration.

Typically you would have to implement custom provider (that would usually be Windows Azure Cache or SQL Azure) to allow persisted session data across multiple instances.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg185668.aspx

Once logged in (no matter on which instance) you're receiving a cookie with a SessionID in it.

Further requests to any instance will cause the application to request your session data from the configured provider.

Comment: But the code I pasted above, it's working without implementing any custom provider. My original question was why?

Comment: Your code is only checking that Session is not null (which shouldn't be regardless of session state).

You're also adding some values to the session date, but you don't check/log/compare them anywhere later to verify you're getting the same value across instances.